# search function in laravel wont work

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have this search bar inside navigation file and it's an enter submit input tag.

I include this file in many pages. but when I enter(submit) it doesn't go to searchResults.blade.php

MY HTML

```
<input class="searchkey" id="searchkey" type="search" required  onkeydown="search(this)">
```

My JS

```
$('.searchkey').keydown(function(event) {
    var getKeyword = document.getElementById("searchkey").value;

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       $.ajax({
             url: "search",
             type: "POST",
             data:{
                  getKeyword : getKeyword
                  },
             success: function() {}

       });
     }         
});
```

MY CONTROLLER

```
public function multiSearch()
{
    $searchKey = Input::get('getKeyword');
    $getResults = array();
    $getResults = DB::select("SELECT title FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%$searchKey%'");
    return View::make('content.searchResults',array('getResults'=>$getResults)); 

}
```

MY ROUTES

```
Route::post('search', 'UserController@multiSearch');
```

Comment: Where is the form?

Comment: you think only the form tag is missing?

Comment: Without form how can you submit data to your requested file?

Comment: And if you are not posting data just change `Route::post('search', 'UserController@multiSearch');
` POST route to this get one and try `Route::get('search', 'UserController@multiSearch');`

Comment: thanks, gonna try that

Comment: it will return a book even if the keyword is not in the books table

Comment: Add a check `if(searchKey)` then do something else do something else

Comment: the $searchKey = Input::get('getKeyword'); is empty, I cant get the keyword I inputted in my html(searchbar)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using ajax instead of just a regular form?

The reason it won't show is because you don't do anything with the result the ajax request gives you. Just sending the request/receiving a response won't be enough, you need to handle the response as well.

Comment: What are you expecting if you're not doing anything here: `success: function() {}` :) You have to add the results to some container.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your ajax callback you should put the view results in some container on the page, i.e.: `<div id="search-result"></div>` by adding this callback function:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#search-reasult').html(data);
}
```

You also have to render the view in your controller like this:

```
return View::make('content.searchResults',array('getResults'=>$getResults))
    ->render();
```